# How can an application administrator remove a Firebase simple login user without knowing their password?

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

My angular app sports a users handling page, where a super-user (administrator) should be able to edit users data. He is not allowed to add new users (who have a sign-up page, where they choose their own secret password), but he should be able(according to my logic) to ***remove*** users...

This is [removeUser()](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/api.md#removeuseremail-password-callback) firebase-simple-login API docs page, and this is a usage example in that same page:

```
auth.removeUser(email, password, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("User removed successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error removing user:", error);
  }
});
```

So, application is supposed to know the password... Should I save user's password in my user's data when she is signing-up?

But this way I'd lose firebase-simple-login's main advantage (avoid storing private/sensible data locally)...

Please explain my mistake, in any...

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to Rob DiMarco comment, I now understand the rationale behild this issue: removeUser() is designed to be used by the user him/herself, after having provided password again... If an admin should need to remove an account, he/she should just set some 'deleted' flag on local user's metadata, and leave that account untouched on firebase. In the event that the user should decide to reactivate that same account, the software should simply remove the 'deleted' flag, and perform a standard `auth.login()` with freshly user provided username/password...

**UPDATE 2**:
The only small problem with this approach (if it is a problem) is that a user who wants to recover a 'deleted' account, *must* remember old password, since we did not remove firebase-simple-login account... However, she can always reset her password, in the "login" form (if she is the real owner of the email account...).

*@Rob DiMarco: if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it...*

Comment: "Should I save user's password in my user's data...?" No. Not ever!

Comment: Rather than outright *removing* the user account, I would recommend an approach where you simple *disable* the account by writing admin-only metadata to the user account, however those records are stored and structured in your Firebase. Then you may use security rules against this 'locked' / 'disabled' flag, and get the functionality you're after without the need to store user passwords.

Comment: Nice one Rob. Can you provide that as an answer?

Comment: @Frank: of course saving passwords locallyYes, it's a good idea, Rob... I am just concerned about the impossibility to re-use the same email to register a new account again after deletion, if not deleted on firebase,too... I mean: when I should receive a new registration attempt of a previously removed account (i.e: with a 'locked' email address), what should I do? That email should be locked forever... :-(

Comment: @Rob: yes, it's a good idea... I am just concerned about the situation when I should need to re-use the same email to register a new account again after deletion, if not deleted on firebase,too... I mean: when I should receive a new registration attempt of a previously removed account (i.e: with a 'locked' email address), what should I do? I could call `auth.$login('password', { email: user.email, password: user.password })`, probably... to avoid to let that email locked forever... (sorry, this idea popped to my mind just when writing this comment... :-). Do you think it's a feasible strategy?

Comment: @MarcoS Sure, seems feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than outright *removing* the user account, I would recommend an approach where you simple disable the account by writing admin-only metadata to the user account, however those records are stored and structured in your Firebase.

Then you may use security rules against this 'locked' / 'disabled' flag, and get the functionality you're after without the need to store user passwords.

Comment: is there an example of this you can point to? I still feel it is a big miss on the API not to allow for a passwordless removal even if you have a grace period where the user-profile is just "marked" as deleted.

Comment: Also I guess the firebase admin website is using an undocumented API call to allow for the manual removal of users through the GUI.